# Import data from Google Play Store into R

Tags: r, google-play

Is there any package or API through which I can import the data form Google Play Store to R. I want to import the data for ratings, reviews about my app.

Answer (score 1):

How about [rvest](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rvest/index.html)? I have tried it on IMDB and it worked great. Google Play Store seems to follow roughly the same format. It should work.